# How to share objects with other activities?

Tags: android

My program has a range of different class activities (basically different screens). In one activity I am creating multiple objects which I would then like to access in other activities.

How do I go about making these objects accessible to other activities within my program, in other words how do I share objects with other activities?

TIA

Mark

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to exchange data (objects) between different Android Activities?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367586/how-to-exchange-data-objects-between-different-android-activities)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to resolve is the operation order. If activity A is the one with the shared objects, what would you do if activity B is run without activity A ever being initialized? Do remember that intents to start activities may come from everywhere, though, to be truthful, exiting with NULL pointer dereference is an acceptable response.

What I did when such a thing was necessary was to not have the shared objects part of the activity, but create a specific object for containing those. You can then store a static reference to that object inside the object, and return it via a static method:

```
public class GlobalParams {
    private static reference;

    public static GlobalParams getReference()
    {
        if( reference==NULL )
            reference=new GlobalParams();
        return reference;
    }
}
```

I don't think parcelable would help you, as that would create distinct copies for the different Activities to use.

Shachar

Answer (score 1):

You need to have that class implement [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html)
It's basically kinda similar to Java's serializable. You have to tell your class how to pack and unpack itself. Then you can just put it in an intent via intent.putExtra();

Here is the code example taken from that link

```
public class MyParcelable implements Parcelable {
     private int mData;

     public int describeContents() {
         return 0;
     }

     public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
         out.writeInt(mData);
     }

     public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable> CREATOR
             = new Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable>() {
         public MyParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
             return new MyParcelable(in);
         }

         public MyParcelable[] newArray(int size) {
             return new MyParcelable[size];
         }
     };

     private MyParcelable(Parcel in) {
         mData = in.readInt();
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Frank.

OK, that just about makes sense - I'm new to Android / Java / OO. Is the use of parcelable a common approach to sharing objects in Android?

Comment: Well this approach is to share objects via an Intent. It's not really a global way to share things. As we learn in intro programming globals are bad, lol. However, the way todo it in Android would be to have a class that extends Application and then all your components can reference that (since they running in the application) to get back references to your shared objects. "If you new to stack too don't forget to upvote answers that help :)"

Comment: Strangely enough, the manual page for 
[Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) suggest use of my approach over yours.