# How to exchange an object between different Android Activities?

Tags: android, android-intent

My application has a list of clients (with only name and age displayed) and I want to be able to edit/add more info about them that is not visible in the list.
So whenever I click on a client, I want to start a second activity with all the info about him.

Can I use an intent for this? Can I pass a full Object (Client) at once with an intent?

I've looked through these two topics, but I haven't found my answer yet:

[How to exchange data (objects) between different Android Activities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367586/how-to-exchange-data-objects-between-different-android-activities)

[How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this answer: [How to pass an object from one activity to another on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-object-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android)

```
//to pass :
intent.putExtra("MyClass", obj);  

// to retrieve object in second Activity
getIntent().getSerializableExtra("MyClass");
```

Comment: I get the "Cannot resolve method" error when I use putExtra() method. This is how I'm trying to send the intent: NewEntry client = ClientsList.get(position); Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, ParseClient.class); intent.putExtra("MyClient", client); startActivity(intent); What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look into saving these in the [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) file. Build a singleton AppUtil class and add functionality to save data in the shared preferences there as well as being able to retrieve said data

If you have a large amount of information being stored for the clients then you should look into [SQLite](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) as database storage.

Answer (score 0):

The more pratice way is create a class to hold every objects that you need to change between the activities. Like that:

```
public class MyHolderObjects {
    public static MyObjectType mObject;
}
```

before start the new activity (or whatever you goes to use it), instantiate (create) the object in MyHolderObjects. And use it everywhere you need :). I prefer this approach instead serialize the object.